# Cannot understand applying structure pointers and arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

Alright, so I'm given the task of creating a gradebook that will:

- Add students
- Add courses
- Add students to courses
- Add grades to students per course
- Avg grades by course
- Avg grades by student

The last one is what's giving me the trouble. I had to turn this project in last week sometime so I used a cheap workaround that basically made the user write down a "Grade ID" for every grade transaction they did so if they wanted the average of anything, they just needed to put in any number of Grade ID's and it averaged those. Now we are going back to this code and implementing some other aspects to it but I really need to figure out how to make this more like a realistic program. It would allow the user to just put in a student ID and get their specific grade average instead of having to know each of that student's Grade ID's. But... I just can't figure out how to do this.

So I scrapped my old idea, and started over and have gotten to the point where I hit the wall last time and forced the workaround. I have the part I am stuck at commented out. This is my addenroll function that will add students to courses, and will be a very similar code to my code where I add grades to specific students.

I can upload my structures code.. the rest of the .c program, etc. I just didn't want my post to span so many pages!

```
void addenroll(enrollment * stuff, courses * cstuff, students *sstuff)                              
{                                                                                                                               
    int i,j;
    int temp;

    printf("Please enter the course ID you would like to add students to.\n");  
    scanf("%d",&temp);

    for(i = 0; i<cstuff->course_cnt;i++)
    {
        if(temp == cstuff->course_list[i].course_id)
        {
            stuff->enroll_list[stuff->enroll_cnt].e_course_id    = temp;
        }
    }

    printf("How many students would you like to add?\n");
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    for(i=0; i<choice; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the Student ID you would like to add to Course: %d\n", stuff->enroll_list[stuff->enroll_cnt].e_course_id);
        scanf("%d", &temp);

        for(j=0;j<sstuff->stu_cnt;j++)
            if(temp == sstuff->stu_list[j].stu_id)                  //Storing the student ID here 
            {
                printf("id match success\n\n");
                //Here is where I got stuck last time...
                //I know this has matched correctly, and here is where I would add a student to a course
                //Also, later when adding grades I'll need to use this same sort of thing to find the corresponding student
                //Just no idea how...
                //I will have this enroll_list[this #].*e_stu_id point to my stu_list[j].stu_id  
                //But I'm not sure of the format to put this in, and also once I have this done
                //I need to add grades here that I can find and average easily on a per course basis since each
                //enrollment only holds one course so I need only to average each enrollment. The problem comes when
                //I need only to find the average of a particular student, as the grades will be stored in an array held
                //ONLY inside this specific enrollment. And since it is in this enrollment, it will not be
                //matched with any particular student anymore, just an array full of grades.
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a couple of ideas come immediately to mind.

1) for the student, traverse their sub records, 
   accumulating the count of grades and the sum of grades.
   then when at the end of the traversal, calculate the average

2) add fields one for the number of grades, one for the sum of the grades
   update those two fields when a grade is added
   and when the average is needed, use those two fields
```

Comment: My problem is, for example: 

User decides to add a student to a class. So my program goes to enroll_list[0].e_course_id; Say there are 5 students added here. Then in enroll_list[0].grades is an array of all the grades in that enrollment. But when they add another class, say only 3 students are put into enroll_list[1]... the grades there are being held by a per enroll_list, not linked by student id. It's just an array inside enroll_list[#] so I can get the average per class, I just don't know how to keep track of the students per ID.